# Reference request: Differential graded structures in mixed characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, differential-graded-algebras

I am looking for references/papers on differential graded structures and their applications in mixed characteristic. The following I have discuss differential graded algebras in the general, not in the mixed characteristic case:

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/dga.pdf

https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0369

https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~mbooth/hodgeproject.pdf

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-658-25338-7_3

In particular, if there are any interesting applications, papers, examples of dg algebras in mixed characteristic, then I would gladly like to know! There doesn’t seem to be an in depth book (from my search so far) about this.